# When onFling is performed?

Tags: android, onfling

I don't understand when onfling (from OnGestureListener) is performed.
Only works when I shake the mouse through the emulator screen. Thanks!

Comment: when swipe the finger on any layout where you ontouch call. Then onfling method trigger automatic

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered how works :)
I saw that onFling is only called when scrolls and let up rapidly. Otherwise doesn't work.